# Rescued Minifigure ID, read torso with armor and yellow head with mustache and glasses

Tags: part-identification

I found this poor guy in a stream by a school. I assume the pieces are cobbled together, but I want the ID of the head and body, as I might be able to salvage them.

[image] [image]

Keep being awesome, guys!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are right,
the parts are from different minifigs:

- The head is [Minifig, Head Moustache Brown Hair, Glasses on Forehead, Raised Eyebrow Pattern - Blocked Open Stud](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=3626bpx32&in=M)
- The torso is
  [Torso Armor White with Black Muscles Outline and White Belt Pattern / Red Arms / Pearl Gold Hands](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=973pb1858c01&in=M)
- The legs are [Hips and Dark Blue Legs](http://www.bricklink.com/catalogItemIn.asp?P=970c63&in=M)

Comment: Those pearl gold hands will be a pain to find.